# Can we set an array of 32 bit int as a key's value in Redis as binary data in node.js?

Tags: arrays, node.js, redis

I want use node.js to set array of int into redis as binary data,each int number must be 4 byte.
How can I do and get it ?
The value can be

```
var arr=[0,1,2,3,4];
var arr=new Int32Array([0,1,2,3]);
```

or some other types,as long as it's node.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The node-redis client supports sending buffers as command arguments. To convert a 32-bit typed array to a raw `Buffer`, you'll need to create an 8-bit typed array from the 32-bit array's buffer view. When creating a redis connection, pass configuration `{return_buffers: true}` to prevent the client from converting command replies to JavaScript values.

```
function setArray (key, untypedArray, fn) {
      var int32 = new Int32Array(untypedArray),
        int8 = new Int8Array(int32.buffer),
        bytes = new Buffer(int8);

      redis.set(key, bytes, fn);
 }

  function getArray (key, fn) {
     var bytes = redis.get(key, function (err, bytes) {
        if(err) return fn(err);
        var int32 = new Int32Array(bytes.toArrayBuffer());
        fn(null, int32);
      });
  }

var redis = require('redis').createClient({return_buffers: true});

setArray('bytes', [22,33, 1 << 31], function () {
    getArray('bytes', console.log);
});
```

This is not a cross-platform solution as typed arrays use the native byte order. To ensure that you always set and get big- or little-endian values, use [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView):

Comment: Thank you very much!
There is a small bug:
  var int32 = new Int32Array(bytes.toArrayBuffer());
I change to:
var int32 = new Int32Array(bytes);
,then it's ok~

Comment: But if I write my program that way,the program report error:
.../node_modules/redis/index.js:602
                throw err;
                      ^
TypeError: Object

Comment: That's because you're missing the {`return_buffers: true`} configuration in `redis.createClient`. The redis client is converting the result of `get` to a string, which doesn't have a `toArrayBuffer` method.

Comment: I see ,thanks again!My program doesn't work because my node version is 0.10.x,there is no toArrayBuffer() method,it's runs correctly in 0.11.9.